# Bootstrap 4's media object with pre inside doesn't respect container's width

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, pre

I placed [media object](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/media-object/) inside bootstrap's column. If I put `<pre><code>...<code></pre>` with long strings of code into `.media-body`, whole `media object` goes outside column's borders.

Here's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crazypilot/8dyq4v7x/16/

Help me, please!

---

UPD: I want to have horizontal scroll on that `<pre><code>...<code></pre>`, so `.media` will not overflow on the column's width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.media-body {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

40px = width of image.

Better approach:

```
.media {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.media-body {
    width: 100%;
}
```